# How to duplicate list elements?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list

```
S = {3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5};
```

and I want every element to be duplicated as many times as the value of the next element.

Note: the last element should be duplicated as many times as the value of the first element.

The result should look like this:

> {{3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {6}, {1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {5, 5, 5}}

Comment: Like this: `ConstantArray[#1, #2] & @@@ Partition[Flatten[{S, First[S]}], 2, 1]`

Comment: very nice thanx.I found something that it works ,too!       Table @@@ Table[{S[[i]], S[[Mod[i, 6] + 1]]}, {i, 1, Length@S}]

Comment: @Anjan, `ConstantArray @@@ Partition[S, 2, 1, 1]` is shorter; `Table @@@ Partition[S, 2, 1, 1]` even more so.

Comment: @J.M I agree yours is very short. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another one:

```
MapThread[ConstantArray, {S, RotateLeft[S]}]
```

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** Using `Partition` with its undocumented sixth argument:

```
Partition[#, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, ConstantArray] & @ {3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5}
```

> {{3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {6}, {1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}}

---

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[f0, f1, f2]
f0 = Table @@@ ({#, {##2, #} & @@ #} &@#) &;
f1 = Developer`PartitionMap[Internal`RepetitionFromMultiplicity@{#} &, #, 2, 1, 1] &;
f2 = Developer`PartitionMap[ConstantArray @@ # &, #, 2, 1, 1] &;
f3 = Normal@SparseArray[{}, {#}, #2] & @@@ ({#, {##2, #} & @@ #} &@#) &;

f0 @ {3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5}
```

> `{{3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {6}, {1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {5, 5, 5}}`

```
Equal @@ (#@{3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5} & /@ {f0, f1, f2, f3})
```

> True

For fun:

```
☺ = {#} //. {♯1___, ♯2_, ♯3___}/;♯2>1 :> {♯1, 1, ♯2 - 1, ♯3} &;
☺☺ = # (☺ /@ {##2, #} & @@ #) &;
☺☺ @ {3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5}
```

> {{3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {6}, {1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {5, 5, 5}}

Answer (score 7):

It's a one-liner. Use [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) to split the list up into pairs, with the offset and cyclic arguments to get what you want, and then apply [`ConstantArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantArray.html) to each pair.

```
ClearAll[duplicate];
duplicate[list : {___Integer}] := ConstantArray @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1, 1];

duplicate[S]
(* {{3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {6}, {1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {5, 5, 5}}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5};

Table @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1, 1]
```

{{3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {6}, {1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {5,
5, 5}}

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, using [Inner](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html.en):

```
s // Inner[Table, #, RotateLeft@#, List] &
```

(As per [J.M](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m)'s [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/142060/106) above regarding [Table](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html.en))

**Original Post**

```
s // Inner[NestList[# &, #1, #2 - 1] &, #, RotateLeft@#, List] &
```

> {{3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {6}, {1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {5, 5, 5}}

Alternatively:

```
s // Inner[ConstantArray, #, RotateLeft@#, List] &
```

Answer (score 3):

```
BlockMap[Apply[Table], #, 2, 1] & @ S
```

> ```
> {{3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {6}, {1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
list ={3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5, 3};

Cases[#, {___Integer}, {2}] &@ReplaceList[list, {p___, x_Integer, y_Integer, c___} :> 
{p, ConstantArray[x, y], y, c}]

(* {{3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {6}, {1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {5, 5, 5}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fu = MapIndexed[ConstantArray[S[[#]], RotateLeft[S, #][[1]]] &, 
 Range[1, Length[S]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using `Table` and `Mod`:

```
Table[ConstantArray @@ {#[[i]], #[[Mod[i + 1, Length@#, 1]]]}, {i, Length@#}] &@S

(*{{3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {6}, {1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {5, 5, 5}}*)
```